# how to dynamically change the dbt model names based on condition using jinja

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

{% set markets = ["AU","NZ","SG"] %}

{% for market in markets %}

{{

```
config(

    materialized='view',

    database='databse',

    SCHEMA='dbt_schema',

    name='{{test(market)}}' )
```

here is the macro
{% set markets = ["AU","NZ","SG"] %}

{%- macro test(variable) -%}

{% for market in markets %}

{%- if market =='AU' -%} 'view_1'

{%- elif market =='SG' -%} 'view_2'

{%- endif -%}

{% endfor %}

{%- endmacro -%}

Comment: Dynamic model names is not really something dbt supports as that would break the generation of the model dag.